# 'react-scripts' build embedding some images in CSS as data-uri's

Tags: css, reactjs, optimization, npm, sass

I've just inherited a large React project. I do not have much experience with React but I'm trying to make some improvements where I know how.

One issue we have is that our main CSS file is huge and one of the main reasons for this is that a bunch of images used in `background-image` properties have been embedded as Data-URIs despite them being set to relative URLs in the original SASS files.

These images are used multiple times throughout the app and so we end up with a final CSS file that has the same images embedded multiple times!

The application is built using `react-scripts build` which I believe is the culprit. As stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files):

> To reduce the number of requests to the server, importing images that
>   are less than 10,000 bytes returns a data URI instead of a path.

I don't want this. Is there a way I can disable this? The project isn't using Webpack or any other build tool/bundler. All I have is the scripts in `package.json` to play with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this with a simple toggle, since create-react-app isn't very customizable by design.

In order to change any configuration you'd like, you have a couple of options:

- Forking the configuration (https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/), which allows you to modify the configuration but still stay within create-react-app's boundaries.
- Ejecting (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-eject) which will irreversably give you full power over the build configuration (which means you also have to maintain it going forward).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: There was an [env var added](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) around 2018 that allowed for the adjustment of this size, for instance:

```
export IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT=1000
```